# Intellisense missing for VB.NET projects in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2005, I can't seem to get the Intellisense menu to pop up at all when I click CTRL+Space. This seems to be limited to VB.NET files. I have tried creating new Visual C# and C# web projects, and it works fine there. There also doesn't seem to be a problem in things like CSS files in VB.NET projects. But when I create a new VB.NET web site, CTRL+Space does nothing. I have tried resetting all the Import and Export setting. That didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Vote-to-close for being 'too localized': this is a valid question which hopefully has a concrete answer. It's obviously some kind of configuration problem with Visual Studio and it is one that cannot be fixed by simply resetting the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SP1 installed?
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bb4a75ab-e2d4-4c96-b39d-37baf6b5b1dc&displaylang=en

If you're using a Microsoft Laser Mouse chances they are interfering with Intellisense.